# Styling antd Button component with emotion and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, emotion

I'm trying to style an antd Button component using emotion in typescript, but when trying to use the Button I get the following error:

> Type '{ children: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

Here is the declaration of the style:

```
const SubmitButton = styled(Button)`
     background-color: #000000;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     cursor: pointer;
`;
```

Then when I try to use it in my React component simply like:

```
render() {
      return (
           <div>
                <SubmitButton>CLICK ME</SubmitButton>
           </div>
      );
}
```

It's showing the definition of the styled button is:

```
(alias) const SubmitButton: StyledComponent<never, Pick<never, never>, any>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?  Below are my dependencies:

- "antd": "^3.15.1"
- "react": "^16.8.4"
- "typescript": "3.3.3333"
- "@emotion/core": "^10.0.9"
- "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.9"

Answer (score 0):

Children of some component should be array of never, but not never.  So you need to figure out which component throw this error.